# how properly to add unadopted function for pet-shop-tutorial

Tags: solidity, truffle

I am learing pet-shop tutorial on truffle and now i want to add an unadopted
  function h have added a one, is this logic true and also  the implementation of it and if not what is the proper approach to add unadopted(buyers can delete their bought pet and returns money back to seller account ) function

below is my code 
what i have gone so far

**thanks in advance**

```
**TestAdoption.sol**


pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "contracts/Adoption.sol";


contract TestAdoption {
  Adoption adoption = Adoption(DeployedAddresses.Adoption());



// Testing the adopt() function
    function testUserCanAdoptPet() public {
      uint returnedId = adoption.adopt(8);

      uint expected = 8;

      Assert.equal(returnedId, expected, "Adoption of pet ID 8 should be recorded.");
    }



// Testing retrieval of a single pet's owner
function testGetAdopterAddressByPetId() public {
  // Expected owner is this contract
  address expected = this;

  address adopter = adoption.adopters(8);

  Assert.equal(adopter, expected, "Owner of pet ID 8 should be recorded.");
}



// Testing retrieval of all pet owners
function testGetAdopterAddressByPetIdInArray() public {
// Expected owner is this contract
address expected = this;

// Store adopters in memory rather than contract's storage
address[16] memory adopters = adoption.getAdopters();

Assert.equal(adopters[8], expected, "Owner of pet ID 8 should be recorded.");
}







// testUnadoptePet bypet_id


  function testUnAdoped() public{


      address expe = this;

      address adopter = adoption.unAdopt(8);

      Assert.equal(adopter, expe, "no owner");


 }




}
```

**Adoption.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Adoption {


address[16] public adopters;

// Adopting a pet
function adopt(uint petId) public returns (uint) {
  require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 15);

  adopters[petId] = msg.sender;

  return petId;
}


// Retrieving the adopters
function getAdopters() public view returns (address[16]) {
  return adopters;
}


    // removed
  //  function removeAddress(address _addr) public {
  //      uint id = arrayIndexes[_addr];
  //      delete sellers[id];
  //  }



   function unAdopt(uint petid) public returns(address){


         address expected = msg.sender;

         address onwer = adopters[petid];

           require(expected == onwer );
             delete adopters[petid];

              return onwer;



      }

}
```

**app.js**

```
App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},

  init: function() {
    // Load pets.
    $.getJSON('../pets.json', function(data) {
      var petsRow = $('#petsRow');
      var petTemplate = $('#petTemplate');

      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
        petTemplate.find('.panel-title').text(data[i].name);
        petTemplate.find('img').attr('src', data[i].picture);
        petTemplate.find('.pet-breed').text(data[i].breed);
        petTemplate.find('.pet-age').text(data[i].age);
        petTemplate.find('.pet-location').text(data[i].location);
        petTemplate.find('.btn-adopt').attr('data-id', data[i].id);

        petsRow.append(petTemplate.html());
      }
    });

    return App.initWeb3();
  },

  initWeb3: function() {
    // Is there an injected web3 instance?
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
    } else {
      // If no injected web3 instance is detected, fall back to Ganache
      App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
    }
    web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);

    return App.initContract();
  },

  initContract: function() {
    //till in /src/js/app.js, remove the multi-line comment from within initContract and replace it with the following:

    $.getJSON('Adoption.json', function(data) {
      // Get the necessary contract artifact file and instantiate it with truffle-contract
      var AdoptionArtifact = data;
      App.contracts.Adoption = TruffleContract(AdoptionArtifact);

      // Set the provider for our contract
      App.contracts.Adoption.setProvider(App.web3Provider);

      // Use our contract to retrieve and mark the adopted pets
      return App.markAdopted();
    });
    return App.bindEvents();

  //  the below code is added by habib_saberi
    return App.bindEvents2();
  },

  bindEvents: function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-adopt', App.handleAdopt);
  },






//  the below code is added by habib_saberi
  // bindEvents2: function() {
  //   $(document).on('click', '.btn-unadopt', App.unAdopted);
  // },


//  unAdopt_functon

unAdopted: function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var petId = parseInt($(event.target).data('id'));

  var unadoptionInstance;

  web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

    var account = accounts[0];

    App.contracts.Adoption.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      unadoptionInstance = instance;

      // Execute adopt as a transaction by sending account
      return unadoptionInstance.unAdopt(petId, {from: account});
    }).then(function(result) {
      return App.unmarkAdopted();
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
  });
}
// end unAdopt_functon




// unmarkAdopted


  unmarkAdopted: function(adopters, account) {
    var unadoptionInstance;


    App.contracts.Adoption.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      unadoptionInstance = instance;

      return unadoptionInstance.getAdopters.call();
    }).then(function(adopters) {
      for (i = 0; i < adopters.length; i++) {
        if (adopters[i] == '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000') {
          $('.panel-pet').eq(i).find('.unbtn-adopt').text('appliedUnadoped').attr('enable', false);
        }
      }
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
  },


// end of unmarkAdopted


  markAdopted: function(adopters, account) {
    var adoptionInstance;


    App.contracts.Adoption.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      adoptionInstance = instance;

      return adoptionInstance.getAdopters.call();
    }).then(function(adopters) {
      for (i = 0; i < adopters.length; i++) {
        if (adopters[i] !== '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000') {
          $('.panel-pet').eq(i).find('.btn-adopt').text('Success').attr('disabled', true);
        }
      }
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
  },


  handleAdopt: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var petId = parseInt($(event.target).data('id'));

    var adoptionInstance;

    web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }

      var account = accounts[0];

      App.contracts.Adoption.deployed().then(function(instance) {
        adoptionInstance = instance;

        // Execute adopt as a transaction by sending account
        return adoptionInstance.adopt(petId, {from: account});
      }).then(function(result) {
        return App.markAdopted();
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
    });
  }

};

$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    App.init();
  });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Pete's Pet Shop</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-push-2">
          <h1 class="text-center">Pete's Pet Shop</h1>
          <hr/>
          <br/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="petsRow" class="row">
        <!-- PETS LOAD HERE -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="petTemplate" style="display: none;">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default panel-pet">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Scrappy</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <img alt="140x140" data-src="holder.js/140x140" class="img-rounded img-center" style="width: 100%;" src="https://animalso.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Golden-Retriever_6.jpg" data-holder-rendered="true">
            <br/><br/>
            <strong>Breed</strong>: <span class="pet-breed">Golden Retriever</span><br/>
            <strong>Age</strong>: <span class="pet-age">3</span><br/>
            <strong>Location</strong>: <span class="pet-location">Warren, MI</span><br/><br/>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-adopt" type="button" data-id="0">Adopt</button>
            <button class="unbtn-adopt" type="button" data-id="0">Adopt</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/web3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/truffle-contract.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what’s the error you are getting?

Comment: it is syntax error in javascript console

Comment: the error is  in app.js file